# Get intersection of a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, intersection

#### Starting Point

I have a multi-dimensional array, like the follow example:

```
$array = array (
  'role_1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  ),
  'role_2' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_1',
    1 => 'value_2',
  ),
  'role_3' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  ),
)
```

#### Goal

I like to loop about the sub-arrays to get only the intersection. The array was created dynamically, can have a lot of sub-arrays `role_[x]` and also a lot of key/value inside the sub-arrays. The key is not necessary, only the value. The key is also a count, not a string.

As result I like to get in this example this small array.

`$array = array( 'value_2' )`

The index, "the array-name", like `role_1` of the sub-arrays is not more relevant after intersection. Important for me in the result is the values, only the values there are existed in each sub-array.

#### Try

I had tried with the source, but I think it is possible much simpler.

```
$value_stack = array();
$result = array();
$i = 0;
foreach( $settings_ as $role => $values ) {

    foreach( $values as $value ){

        if( in_array( $value,$value_stack ) || $i === 0 ) {
            $result[ $role ][] = $value;
        }

        $value_stack[] = $value;
    }
    $i++;

};
```

The merge of this multi array result should run with a `array_merge` in a loop.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `$temp = $array[0]; for ($i = 1; $i < count($array) -1; $i++) { $temp = array_intersect($temp, $array[$i]); }`

Comment: Thanks for your fast hint, but this is always `NULL` in my tests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to cover the dynamic `$data` as such:

```
$data = array (
  'role_1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  ),
  'role_2' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_1',
    1 => 'value_2',
  ),
  'role_3' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  )
);

$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $data);
```

[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) will help spread the elements of your array as parameters inside `array_intersect`.

Comment: array_intersect() does not accept unknown named parameters - PHP Version 8

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array_of_arrays)
```

This will pass each element of your array of arrays as an argument to `array_intersect`, which takes a variable number of arrays as arguments and returns their intersection.

Comment: The result of this is always `NULL`. I had tried this.

Comment: @bueltge Have you also tried with *`call_user_func_array`*?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should have been `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: For the protocol: at first the answer was with the function `call_user_func`. The switch to `call_user_func_array` is really helpful. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php) work for this:

```
$data = array (
  'role_1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  ),
  'role_2' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_1',
    1 => 'value_2',
  ),
  'role_3' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value_2',
    1 => 'value_3',
  )
);


$result = array_intersect($data['role_1'], $data['role_2'], $data['role_3']);
print_r($result);
```

result :

```
Array ( [0] => value_2 )
```

Comment: I'd assume the number of roles is unknown, so this call style is a bit impractical.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.6+ the [splat/spread operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) can be used to unpack the arguments in a call to [`array_intersect()`](https://php.net/array_intersect). In order to remove the non-numeric keys from the array, pass `$array` to a call to [`array_values()`](https://php.net/array_values).

```
$result = array_intersect(...array_values($array));
```

See a demonstration in [this playground example](https://tehplayground.com/Py0jbC4VO6WJxr4k).