# how to split arrays inside a big array to fit intersect function?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-intersect

I have the following array that contains other arrays:

```
$bigArray = [$array_one, $array_two, $array_three,.... ];
```

I want to `array_intersect` the inner arrays like so:

```
$intersect = array_intersect($array_one, $array_two, $array_three,....);
```

How do I handle it?

Comment: [check this for other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056228/get-intersection-of-a-multiple-array-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$intersect = array_intersect(...$bigArray);
```

The [`...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) operator, [introduced in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat), allows you to use an array to pass multiple function arguments.

It's also possible to do this with `call_user_func_array`, but argument unpacking offers [some advantages](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking#advantages_over_call_user_func_array) over that approach.

Comment: call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $bigArray);

this also works for me

Comment: @SolimanMahmoudSoliman yes, before PHP 5.6, that was the standard way to do this. You can check out the RFC for more info: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking, specifically the "Advantages over call_user_func_array" section.

Answer (score 1):

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $bigArray);
```

this works for me